# Modificar elementos de una misma clase en DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas si bien vi varias preguntas de este tipo ninguna resuelve mi inconveniente, tengo en una pagina varios p con la misma clase ".more" en la cual c/u contiene un texto diferente, tengo que logar que si el texto contenido es muy largo lo acorte y agregue un botón leer +, el tema es que lo logre, pero siempre me imprime el mismo texto del primer p en todos los p ".more".

```
<p class=".more">Primer texto</p>
<p class=".more">Segundo texto con mas caranteres</p>
<p class=".more">Tercer texto</p>
```

en el jquery

```
$(function(){
    var showChar = 5;
    var content = document.querySelectorAll('.more');
   var ellipsestext = "...";
   var moretext = "Seguir leyendo ...";
   var lesstext = "Mostrar menos";

for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  if(content[i].innerHTML.length > showChar) {
    var c = content[i].innerHTML.substr(0, showChar);

      html = '<div class="abstract">' + c + ellipsestext + '</div>' + '<div class="morecontent">' + content[i].innerHTML + '</div>' + '<p><span class="morelink">' + moretext + '</span></p>'; 

     $('.more').html(html);
  }
}

});
```

bueno traté de resumirlo al código para ver el problema nada mas, para mi que el problema esta en $('.more').html(html); por que siempre asigna lo mismo a todos los p

me hace esto, agregando la clase abstact si se cumple la condición de ser menor a 5 caracteres... que lo omití para no poner tanto código.

```
<p class=".more">Primer texto</p>
<p class=".more">Primer texto</p>
<p class=".more">Primer texto</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//Definimos una variable tipo objeto donde se almacenará el texto original
var originalText = {
}
//definimos una constante donde pondremos el maximo de caracteres a mostrar
const caracteres = 18;

//Recorremos cada uno de los elementos que tengan la clase moretext
$('.moreText').each(function(index,element){
  
  //Almacenamos el texto original en la variable originalText
  originalText[index] = $(this).text();
  //le asignamos un atributo para poder identificarlo y agregarle el texto completo cuando se le dé click
  $(this).attr('nIdTag', index);
  
  //Hacemos una validación si el texto es mas grande que los caracteres permitidos
  if(originalText[index].length > caracteres){
    //Acortamos el texto y añadimos una etiqueta B que al dar click disparará el evento que hara el funcionamiento deseado
    $(this).html(originalText[index].substr(0,caracteres)+'... <b class="verMas" style="cursor:pointer">Mostrar Más</b>')
  }
  
})



function agregarEventos(){
  
  $('.verMas').off('click')
  //Añadimos el evento a la clase .verMas de la etiqueta B
  $('.verMas').on('click',function(){
    //Obtenemos la etiqueta padre del elemento al que hacemos click
    var padre = $(this).parents('.moreText');
    //accedemos al atributo nIdTag que seteamos como identificador
    var nIdTag = padre.attr('nIdTag')
    // ya teniendo el identificador le ponemos el texto original al
    //padre con ayuda del objeto originalText y el identificador
    //EDIT
    //Agregamos la etiqueta B para el funcionamiento de ver menos
    padre.html(originalText[nIdTag]+'... <b  style="cursor:pointer" class="verMenos'+nIdTag+'">Ver Menos</b>')

    //Definimos el comportamiendo del evento click
    $('.verMenos'+nIdTag).on('click',function(){
    
      if(originalText[nIdTag].length > caracteres){
          //El funcionamiento es similar al del primer bloque
         padre.html(originalText[nIdTag].substr(0,caracteres)+'... <b class="verMas" style="cursor:pointer">Mostrar Más</b>')
         agregarEventos();
      }
    })
  })
}

agregarEventos();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="moreText">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p class="moreText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porta arcu at egestas ultricies. Proin.</p>
<p class="moreText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras consequat auctor dui, a efficitur dui rutrum eget. Quisque egestas eleifend.</p>
```

he actualizado la respuesta para la funcionalidad de ver menos... es un poco rustica y puede mejorarse sin embargo cumple con la funcionalidad

Comment: Muchas Gracias Fernado por tu ayuda!

Comment: En el caso que quiera agregarle un leer menos , le agregue en el evento click padre.html(originalText[nIdTag]+ <b class="verMenos" style="cursor:pointer">Mostrar Menos</b> ), y cree ese evento pero no hace nada al clikear, sera que lo tendre que manejar con el attr hide o con un toggle? he intentado pero nada

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta, hice algunos cambios para poder cumplir con la funcionalidad de "ver menos", entiendo que puede ser una forma no tan practica de resolverlo y que puede ser mejorado sin embargo cumple con el propósito.

Comment: Perfecto! ahora si pude entenderlo muchas gracias Fernando!

Comment: En la comunidad estamos para ayudar!.. 
en caso de que te haya servido mi respuesta te agradecería la marcaras como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<p class="more">Primer texto</p>
<p class="more">Segundo texto con mas caranteres!!</p>
<p class="more">Tercer texto</p>
```

CSS

```
.full {
  display: none;
}
.mas {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: green;
}
.menos {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(function(){
    var showChar = 12;
    var content = document.querySelectorAll('.more');
  
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  if(content[i].innerHTML.length > showChar) {
    var c = content[i].innerHTML.substr(0, showChar);
    var d = content[i].innerHTML.substr(showChar, 9999);
    var html = '<div class="container">'
    + '<div class="content">' + c + '<span class="full">'+ d +'</span>'+'</div>'
    + '<span class="mas" onclick="seeMore(this);">...Mas</span>' 
    + '<span class="menos" onclick="seeLess(this);">Menos</span>'
    + '</div>';
     $(content[i]).html(html);
  }
}

});

function seeMore(obj) {
  var full = obj.parentNode.querySelector('.full').style.display = 'inline-flex';
  var less = obj.parentNode.querySelector('.mas').style.display = 'none';
  var less = obj.parentNode.querySelector('.menos').style.display = 'block';
}

function seeLess(obj) {
  var full = obj.parentNode.querySelector('.full').style.display = 'none';
  var less = obj.parentNode.querySelector('.mas').style.display = 'inline-flex';
  var less = obj.parentNode.querySelector('.menos').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Ejemplo
[See more, see less - CodePen](https://codepen.io/FerCatalano/pen/JjLpooK)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).